# In Oracle sql, I want to club rows by removing null columns

Tags: sql, oracle

For eg.,
My table gives below values,

```
  | AppID | Sales           | Salaries     |  Bills   |
  +-------+-----------------+--------------+----------+
  | 7     |54               | Null         |  Null    |
  | 7     |Null             | 66           |  Null    |
  | 7     |Null             | Null         | 88       |
  | 8     |Null             | 7654         | Null     |
  | 8     |Null             | Null         | 72       |
  | 8     |Null             | Null         | 78       |
```

How do i get the result as()

```
 | AppID | Sales           | Salaries     |  Bills   |
  +-------+-----------------+-------------+----------+
  | 7     |54              | 66           |  88      |
  | 8     |Null            | 7654         |  72      |
  | 8     |Null            | Null         | 78       |
```

--Added duplicate values for Appid 8
?

Waiting for answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could use aggregation for this.

`Max`:

```
select appId, 
    max(sales) as sales,
    max(Salaries) as salaries,
    max(Bills) as bills
from your_table
group by appId;
```

or `Sum`:

```
select appId,
    sum(sales) as sales,
    sum(Salaries) as salaries,
    sum(Bills) as bills
from your_table
group by appId;
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. But If I am having multiple values like

Comment: @user3207875 - What do you want to do in that case?

Comment: Input

 | AppID | Sales           | Salaries     |  Bills   |
  +-------+-----------------+--------------+----------+
  | 7     |54               | Null         |  Null    |
  | 7     |Null             | 66           |  Null    |
  | 7     |Null             | Null         | 88       |
  | 8     |Null             | 7654         | Null     |
  | 8     |Null             | Null         | 72       |
  | 8     |Null             | Null         | 78       |

Comment: Output
  
  | AppID | Sales           | Salaries     |  Bills   |
  +-------+-----------------+-------------+----------+
  | 7     |54              | 66           |  88      |
  | 8     |Null            | 7654         |  72      |
  | 8     |Null            | Null         |  78      |

Comment: How to do it in this case?

Comment: @user3207875 - Please add this data in the question. not in the comments..

Comment: Updated the question with duplicate values for Appid 8

Comment: @user3207875 why is salaries 7654 and bills 72? why not the 7654 and 78?

Comment: No such requirement. Just want to club the rows and show the results. Similar requirement I have for other table which has date columns. Trying  for correct solution from 2 hrs. I'm a beginner to Oracle SQL.

Comment: @user3207875 - No. Your question doesn't make any sense now. How to determine which value should come in which row?

Comment: For same appid, values can vary, not an issue. Salaries 7654 and bills 72 or 7654 and 78. Not a problem. Just want to combine and show results.

Comment: @user3207875 . . . Gurwinder answered the question as asked.  If you have another question, accept this answer and ask another question.

Comment: I have upvoted the answer. But this doesn't solve the requirement completely. @Gordon

Answer (score 0):

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table( AppID, Sales, Salaries, Bills ) AS
  SELECT 7, 54, NULL, NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 7, NULL, 66, NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 7, NULL, NULL, 88 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 8, NULL, 7654, NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 8, NULL, NULL, 72 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 8, NULL, NULL, 78 FROM DUAL;
```

**Query**:

```
SELECT AppId,
       Sales,
       Salaries,
       Bills
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY AppId, Column_Name ORDER BY ROWNUM ) rn
  FROM   my_table
  UNPIVOT (value FOR column_name IN (Sales, Salaries, Bills) ) t
)
PIVOT
(
   MAX( value )
   FOR column_name IN (
    'SALES' AS sales, 'SALARIES' AS salaries, 'BILLS' AS bills
   )
)
ORDER BY AppId, rn;
```

**Output**:

```
APPID SALES SALARIES BILLS
----- ----- -------- -----
    7    54       66    88
    8           7654    72
    8                   78
```